# Product of two topologies?

Tags: general-topology

Is the **Cartesian** product of two topologies again topology?

According to my knowledge , NO ? So how the product of two or many topologies defined ?

Could someone make it clear for me. I am new to topology.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Product_topology

Comment: @MikeMiller Dear I went there but it is little bit hard to me to understand. May someone give me some example on it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A topology on $X$ is a set of subsets of $X$. If $\tau$ is a topology on $X$ and $\sigma$ a topology on $Y$, then $\tau\times\sigma$ is *not* a subset of $X\times Y$, in general, because it's a set of pairs of subsets of $X$ and $Y$.

What you can consider is $\mathcal{B}=\{U\times V:U\in\tau, V\in\sigma\}$, that's not the same as $\tau\times\sigma$, but is a set of subsets of $X\times Y$.

However, $\mathcal{B}$ is generally not a topology, because it lacks the property of being closed under unions. Since
$$
(U_1\times V_1)\cap(U_2\times V_2)=
(U_1\cap U_2)\times(V_1\cap V_2)
$$
we deduce $\mathcal{B}$ is closed under finite intersections. In particular $\mathcal{B}$ is a *basis* for the topology $\hat{\mathcal{B}}$ consisting of arbitrary unions of members of $\mathcal{B}$.

This is the product topology, that is, the least topology on $X\times Y$ making the projection maps $X\times Y\to X$ and $X\times Y\to Y$ continuous.

It's clear that every set of the form $U\times V$ with $U\in\tau$ and $V\in\sigma$ must be open in any topology making those maps continuous. Since the least topology containing $\mathcal{B}$ is $\hat{\mathcal{B}}$, we are done.

Comment: Well done I just understood via BASIS. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @ZidanSmko In general a basis for a topology needn't be closed under finite intersections; the required properties are that the intersection of two members is the union of members and that the union of all members is the whole set. In this particular case such properties are obviously satisfied.

Comment: I got it .. Excellent.

Answer (score 1):

This question does not make any sense. You have to define the topology on the product $X\times Y$ by **urself**. However there are many useful/common topologies for the product of the topological spaces. The most common one is the [product-topology](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Product_topology). Another example is the [box-topology](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Box_topology), which is totally the same as the product-topology for **finite products.**

Since you are new to topology. Topology is about defining the open sets by yourself. In your analysis course you considered different function on a fixed topological space (mostly $\mathbb R$ with the standard topology). New it's vice versa. You may look at a fixed function with different topologies.

A question could be: What is the smallest (in terms of inclusion) topology such that a given function is continuous?.. But this would take us to a different topic.

Comment: I mean the cartesian product. Why my question does not make any sense?

Comment: A topological space consists of a set and a topology on it. It is a tuple written as $(X,\tau)$ for example. If you want to look at a product then the set you are considering is indeed $X\times Y$. But if you want to have it as a topological space than you need a suitable topology on that set. So we want $(X\times Y, \tau)$ with $\tau$ beeing a topology on $X\times Y$. Is it clear now?

Comment: @ZidanSmko The elements of $\tau_1 \times \tau_2$ are not subsets of $ X \times Y $. So this could not be a topology. The sane question would be whether $\{ A \times B : A \in \tau_1, B \in \tau_2 \} $ is a topology. It usually isn't, as it turns out.

Comment: What I meant is: suppose we have two $\tau_1$ and $\tau_2$ even on the same space say $X$. Is $\tau_1\times\tau_2$ again topology.

Comment: @Ian How come ? Could you explain it to me?